# React Strap Carousel Exit Animation to showing

Tags: css, reactjs, reactstrap

I am having a strange issue with my carousel on my React application, I am using React strap and the carousel is not animating correctly.

The slide exiting does not exit, instead suddenly disappears and the next slide will correctly slide in. I am using the exact code from the documentation on the reactstrap site but its not behaving in the same manner.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Noxirus